# Opposite of invariant

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, science, scientific-language

I look for the opposite of "invariant" in the context of scientific language.
If you look at this example sentence:

> [...] Although it is translationally and rotationally invariant,
> it is not permutationally invariant. [...]

There is a repetition of the word "invariant" and a double negation. ("not" and "in-" as prefix)

Since I could not find any example of people saying "variant" for "not invariant", I do not know how to nicely write this sentence.

If I look at [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/invariant) and list the possible antonyms:

> changing, deviating, nonuniform, unsteady, varying

I think none is fitting, but I am also not of English mother tongue.

Comment: From programming contexts, ***constant, volatile*** might refer to the attributes ***invariant, variable***.

Comment: *There is a repetition of the word "invariant" and a double negation. ("not" and "in-" as prefix)* There is nothing wrong with this at all. The language is perfect for the context: you change it at your peril...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variant is correct. It can function as an adjective meaning essentially "having variety", and it fits here as "invariant" is also an adjective.

As for why this is not a common use, I can't say. It's perfectly correct and has an appealing familiarity to it. If you're looking for advice relating to the jargon of a specific field, I suggest you consult experts of that field.

Comment: Google finds plenty of examples in scientific papers https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225834750_Equalization_of_rotationally_variant_signals https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228811713_Rotationally_Variant_Grating_Writing_in_Photonic_Crystal_Fibres

Comment: Note, [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/variant) says that *variant* as a synonym for *variable* is obsolete. In other words, if you mean that a thing *contains* variety, it's a reasonable word, but if you mean that it *behaves* inconsistently, then *variable* might be a better choice.

Comment: Another science citation: [*Investigating functions which are invariant under cyclic permutation of their arguments, and their associated **permutationally variant** functions.*](https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/opportunities/careers-for-mathematicians/summer-research-mathematics/pastacademic.html)